# App update- Not everything updated

Tags: android

I've two apk files of same app and 1st one is an old version and 2nd apk new. There's some changes in the 2nd apk(some settings and some extra text). I updated the 1st apk with the second one, and it successfully updated. When I checked the app, I can see the new text but some settings which are changed in the new apk file remains same. Then I fully uninstalled the app and reinstalled the new apk and when I open it, I can see that everything is changed as expected(settings too). So this issue happens only when I update the app. Any idea why this is happening?
ps: I wasn't trying to update via google play. Direct apk update.

Comment: What do you mean by "some settings"?

Comment: preferences to be precise

Comment: I don't understand, can you post some example code of change? Do you talk about SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes you're right. sharedprefernces

Comment: If you update your app then SharedPreferences value will be there, it won't be clear...

Comment: Oh it means sharedprefernces value wont change after update? So, when a new user installs the app from google play, preferences from the latest apk will be used. Am i right?

Comment: simply saying, even after update, old users will have the same old preferences. New users will get new preference. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @user3548321 you can check this answer . create common class for `SharedPref` .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example/29363541#29363541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you are using `sharedpreferences` in your code so it's not update.you can uninstall old version and then install new version or you must write code that clear the `sharedpreferences` do this with:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
preferences.edit().remove("shared_pref_key").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

**SharedPreferences** is application specific, i.e. the data is lost when you perform one of the options:

1. once you uninstall the application
2. once you clear application data (through Settings)

SharedPreference store certain options persistently throughout the lifetime of the application. So when you installing the new version of the apk, the data still intact.

Read more at:

1. [Android Persistence with preferences and files - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)
2. [Storing and Accessing SharedPreferences](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-and-Accessing-SharedPreferences)